# Fast thread-safe read optimised Map[Long, _]

Tags: multithreading, scala, collections

I am looking for suggestions to a fast `Map` with `Long` keys. It will have a lot of read accesses and rather small write/update accesses. Performance should thus focus on read (`get`) access. It must be thread-safe. Some ideas:

1. regular `collection.Map[Long, _]` has to box keys
2. bare bones `collection.mutable` would have to wrap `synchronized` all the time, penalising read access
3. bare bones `collection.immutable` could have unsynchronized read access if stored in a `@volatile` `var`. Update could synchronize.
4. perhaps `TMap` from Scala-STM? But then a `Ref[Map[Long, _]]` probably is as good because concurrent reads should be allowed in STM

To me No. 3 sound best?

Comment: I think volatile will affect the collection itself, not its content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an immutable `LongMap`, and 2.11 will have a mutable `LongMap`.  The latter is not thread-safe, but you could wrap accesses (probably with a read-write lock from `java.util.concurrent`, if you're mostly reading and can reason through possible deadlocks).  If you have a lot of contention, you're unlikely to do much better than just using `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`; threading issues will be much more expensive then than a bit of extra boxing.

Comment: What is the largely in `Note: This class is as of 2.8 largely superseded by HashMap.` on `LongMap`?

Comment: Exactly, I saw the note about being obsolete. Also, since it is in the regular scala.collection type hierarchy, I think it will still box the keys, right?

Comment: @0__ - I am not terribly familiar with `immutable.LongMap`, but it shouldn't box the keys unless you use in a generic context (in which case it will both box and unbox them).  It is true that `immutable.LongMap` hasn't been worked on much.  The mutable one is brand new, though.

Answer (score 2):

`collection.Map` isn't thread-safe by default, but has to use the `SynchronizedMap` trait which is just locking around all accesses - performance wise not so great, probably slower than a simple `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Using an immutable map and a volatile variable which is replaced when updating would work and would be the cheapest possible option read wise (can't get cheaper than a simple volatile read). Expensive when updating though.

No idea how good Scala's STM is, so certainly worth a try too.

One option you should definitely consider, would be Cliff's non-blocking hashmap though, [see here](http://high-scale-lib.sourceforge.net/). It does have a Long version so you avoid boxing and it's performance-wise hard to beat (depending on the situation faster to extremely faster compared to the ConcurrentHashMap in the java stdlib which again is a good deal quicker than just using a normal hashmap and locking around every access).

Comment: thanks for mentioning `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`, might be a good comparison in performance tests

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good use of the either a regular HashMap or the fastutil [Long2Object map](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/longs/AbstractLong2ObjectMap.html) and a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`. That lock will let you have multiple simultaneously open read locks, but write locks have to be exclusive. I'd still benchmark it against `ConcurrentHashMap` because its implementation is known to be pretty good.

Doh! You probably want a Scala answer and not the Java flavor.

Comment: Thanks! I don't care if it's Java or Scala, as long as its compact and open source.